# Data types for storing lng/lat in MySQL

Tags: mysql-spatial

I'm storing a large list of lnt/lat points in a MySQL database. At the moment these are projected points for the UK in M, but in the long term I would like to make sure that I can store the coordinates of points for all over the world.  What datatype should I use?

I started using `decimal(18,12)`, but was unsure whether this precision is needed or whether I could just use a `float`. I included my code, in case there is anything else I should be considering:

```
CREATE TABLE UKTest
(
lat FLOAT,
lng FLOAT
)
```

I'm quite new to SQL so I'm unsure whether the data type is significant when running a query. I assumed that the overall memory would vary based on the variable type. Is there a benefit of using a spatial database over a basic MySQL database for this type of work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This [question was also asked on StackOverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql).

The top answer suggests the [MySQL Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-a-spatially-enabled-mysql-database.html). There are a load of links on working with these extensions [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?23,184702,184702#msg-184702).

If you don't want to use spatial types and you are getting values from a GPS unit, or geocoding service then you can match your decimal precision to the data source. A general rule of thumb is to store data to an accuracy of two places greater than you will be displaying it in an application.

In a [code example from Google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html) displaying points on a map, they state:

> When you create the MySQL table, you want to pay particular attention to the 
>   lat and lng attributes. With the current zoom capabilities of Google Maps, 
>   you should only need 6 digits of precision after the decimal.
>
> To keep the storage space required for
>   our table at a minimum, you can
>   specify that the lat and lng
>   attributes are floats of size (10,6).
>   That will let the fields store 6
>   digits after the decimal, plus up to 4
>   digits before the decimal, e.g.
>   -123.456789 degrees

I wouldn't worry about performance differences between numeric types. Decent indices will have a far greater effect.

Comment: +1 for a good answer! This is what I would have said and done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've read through the MySQL Spatial Extensions documentation, but how do you start to use them? I just have a default MySQL DB on GoDaddy; I don't know where I should start.

Comment: @celenius http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/12147/working-with-spatial-data-in-mysql/

Comment: And answer updated with a link to more links

Comment: Why 4 integer digits?

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are tied to MySQL for some other reason you should really consider using a spatially enabled database like postgis which has a Point (and Line, Polygon etc) object to handle these details for you. You also get projection support for when you make that change to the whole world.

**2019**: For people like me who also do not read comments - MySQL supports spatial data types, supposedly slower, without evidence.

Comment: Note: For those who are new and reading the above, MySql 5.7+ now works with Spatial Indexes.

Comment: but it is still slow

Comment: Could you please help with resources that show how slow ? I am considering using it on a project with less than a million records. Thanks.

Comment: personal experience no public data. Too many issues with invalid geometries etc breaking things

Comment: Thanks. My need is just distance between points based on database records (and no complex requirements like Polygon) -hence will probably be safe to use mysql for now.